# How do I change the dimensions of a View programmatically?

Tags: android, view

I just want an empty view with certain dimensions. 
I declare the reference variable here:

```
public static View sv;
```

I instantiate the view in the onCreate method of my activity:

```
sv = new View(this);
```

and then attempt to set the dimensions right below it:

```
sv.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
```

but when I call sv.getWidth() and sv.getHeight(), they still return 0

Comment: Views may or may not have width and height right away.  You need to be sure that the view has been created and has a width or height before you will probably get back non-zero values.

Answer (score 1):

The height and width only will have value after of the OnCreate() and OnResume(). Try get height and width after this methods.

**UPDATED**

You can use a layout listener for this, depending on your goals. For example, in onCreate():

```
final View view = findViewById(android.R.id.view);
        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                //Now you can change the dimensions
            }
        });
```